# grouping multiple pair of where/wherein conditions together

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

so here s the query i want

```
    $products = Product::whereHas('ProductFilter' , function($q) use ($filter_groups){

            foreach($filter_groups as $k=>$v)
            $q->where('f_id' , $k )->whereIn( 'value' ,$v );

        })->get();
```

which will result in this query

```
select * from `products` where exists 

( 
  select * from `product_filters` where 
 `product_filters`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and 
 `f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' )   and 
 `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34')

)
```

i want to group these line thoghether

```
 `f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' )  
  and 
 `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34')
```

like

```
    ( `f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' )   )
and 
    ( `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34') )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your where clauses by nesting `where()` method calls so your example would look something like this:

```php
$products = Product::whereHas('ProductFilter' , function($q) use ($filter_groups){
    foreach($filter_groups as $k=>$v) {
        $q->where(function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('f_id', $k);
            $query->whereIn('value' ,$v );
        });
    })->get();
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) is the relevant section of the documentation.

Comment: thanx , works great just this `Builder $query` should just be `$query`

Comment: The callback given to the `where()` method will be given instance of a query builder. In your case it would `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. If the query was built without eloquent, it would be `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.